# Do I need SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege to log off a user?

Tags: c++, winapi, logoff

I need to log off a user from a C++ program. I use [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API for that, but I'm not sure from the documentation if I need any special privileges for that?

Comment: No, you don't need any extra privileges from what I know. At my school, I'm able to shut down with the privilege and log off without.

Comment: Thanks. You may want to post it as an answer then. One follow-up question though -- in an enterprise Active Directory environment there's no GPO or a privilege that can limit logging off a user with that API, is there?

Comment: I highly doubt it. If I'm correct, a policy on that would most likely not let the user themself log off. I'm going off of my experiences, though, so I think it would be a good idea to hear from someone who's more confident they know it for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So hopefully someone else reads this thread too ))

Answer (score 1):

You do. Here's an example

```
bool ShutdownWindows(void)
{
HANDLE hToken = NULL; 
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp = {0};
bool bRet = false;

// Get a token for this process. 
if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) {
    if (LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid)) {
        tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;  // one privilege to set    
        tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED; 

        // Get the shutdown privilege for this process. 
        if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, NULL, 0)) {
            ::CloseHandle(hToken);

            if (ERROR_SUCCESS == GetLastError()) {

                DWORD dwFlags = EWX_POWEROFF;
                DWORD dwReason = SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_SYSTEM;

                if (ExitWindowsEx(dwFlags, dwReason)) {
                    bRet = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return bRet;
```

} // ShutdownWindows

Comment: First off, the original question is about logging off users (`EWX_LOGOFF` flag) and not about shutting down the workstation (`EWX_POWEROFF` parameter.) If you're doing that, then indeed `SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` privilege is needed. If it's just `EWX_LOGOFF`, then it is not. Note that your proposed solution will still work though, you'll just give your process an unnecessary privilege.

Comment: Also your code for adjusting token privileges is wrong. You should call `GetLastError()` and make sure it returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` after your call to `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` to make sure that the requested privilege was actually granted. There's also a memory leak in the way `hToken` handle is released.... So I'll just stop there.