# getting access is denied when calling InitiateSystemShutdown

Tags: python, winapi

```py
import win32api
win32api.InitiateSystemShutdown(None,"message",100,1,0)
```

i also tried to run this script as an admin but it didnt work

the error :
`pywintypes.error: (5, 'InitiateSystemShutdown', 'Access is denied.')`

Comment: The remark section of the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdownw#remarks) is pretty clear about what you need to have to call this API. Have you tried to look at your token to see if the `SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` priv is enabled for the calling thread? There's a [nice exemple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/how-to-shut-down-the-system) on MS website on how to proceed (even though it uses `ExitWindowsEx` in the end, it's basically the same).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need SE\_SHUTDOWN\_NAME privilege to log off a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168289/do-i-need-se-shutdown-name-privilege-to-log-off-a-user)